# Unable to save/update field with desired string value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model called `SystemState`. Following is the migration that created this table:

```
create_table :system_states do |t|
  t.string :code
  t.timestamps
end
```

But, even if **code** column is of **string** type, when I do the following:

```
> SystemState.first
> #<SystemState id: 1, code: 0, created_at: "2017-03-14 10:19:45", updated_at: "2017-03-14 10:28:33">

> SystemState.find(1).update_attributes(code: "system_alert_notification")

> SystemState.first
> #<SystemState id: 1, code: 0, created_at: "2017-03-14 10:19:45", updated_at: "2017-03-14 10:29:43">
```

As can be seen, it always updates it as **0**(integer).

Is the column name reserved or something? Keen to know the cause of above.

Comment: It seems there is no comprehensive list of reserved words for columns. Starring this to come back to see the answer later.

Comment: It cannot possibly be a string and show like that in the console. Have you checked in your db or `schema.rb` file? And reloaded the console after any changes?

Comment: @iceman Yes, thanks for the pointer, the schema has it as integer, but I'm unsure how it ended up like that

Comment: What is the output of `SystemState.type_for_attribute('code')` ?

Comment: It cannot be an integer in the db and show up like that in the console, have you checked in your db manager?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this error with Postgres. I created a model as you specified with `code` as a string field, and it works absolutely fine. BTW, what DB are you using?

Comment: @31piy MySQL DB

Comment: Seems like `code` is a reserved word in MySQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possibilities :

1) May be `code` is a reserved word in **mysql**

2) Also, I'm sure, the column in your db is of integer type. Change it to string and it should work.